# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: []("duyuru")

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-getx

// my controller

```
class DuyuruController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  TextEditingController duyuru = TextEditingController();
  Rx<List<DuyuruModel>> duyurumodel = Rx<List<DuyuruModel>>([]);
  List<DuyuruModel> get newsModelList => duyurumodel.value;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    duyurumodel.bindStream(todoStream(uid));
    super.onInit();
  }

  var uid;
  String collection = "duyuru";

  firestoreduyuruekle(String id) {
    uid = new Uuid().v4().toString();
    _firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).doc(uid).set({
      "kullaniciid": id,
      "duyuruid": uid,
      "duyuru": duyuru.text,
    });

    duyuru.clear();
  }

  Stream<List<DuyuruModel>> todoStream(String uid) {
    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection(collection)
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) {
      var data = query.data();
      List veriler = data['duyuru'];
      List<DuyuruModel> retVal = [];
      veriler.forEach((element) {
        retVal.add(DuyuruModel.fromMap(element));
      });
      return retVal;
    });
  }
}
```

// my model

```
 class DuyuruModel {
  static const ID = "duyuruid";
  static const NAME = "duyuru";

  String id;
  String duyuru;

  DuyuruModel({
    this.id,
    this.duyuru,
  });

  DuyuruModel.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    id = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)[ID];
    duyuru = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)[NAME];
  }
}
```

//my ui

```
 class DuyuruWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DuyuruWidgetState createState() => _DuyuruWidgetState();
}

class _DuyuruWidgetState extends State<DuyuruWidget> {
  var deger2 = Get.put<AuthController>(AuthController());
  var deger1 = Get.put<DuyuruController>(DuyuruController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      if (deger1.newsModelList == null) {
        return Text('Loading');
      } else if (deger1.newsModelList.isEmpty) {
        return Text('Empty List');
      } else {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: deger1.newsModelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(deger1.newsModelList[index].duyuru);
          },
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

my error : Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: .
Even though I check for empty, the list is empty, can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjy4L.png)
my firebase database

I'm getting list empty check error but there is announcement data in my database and I'm pulling them but I can't see the data on the screen

Comment: I am seeing you are declaring `uuid` and setting it to new `UUID` and calling `doc` with it. I think your collection shouldn't have any doc with that uuid.

Comment: how can I solve problem ?